# push date into array by value, not by reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, pass-by-value

How do I store dates into an array **by value**?

I suspect that the dates are stored into the array by reference. The problem I'm encountering is that **the array ends up containing multiple entries that are all the same date** i.e. the last calculated workingday.

I'm making a function that will return the next ten workingdays in an array.
The 'while' loop counts the days and stores workingdays into the array that will be returned.

```
        var thedays = getworkingdays();
        console.log(thedays);

        function getworkingdays(){
            var currentdate = new Date();
            i = 0;
            var workingdays = new Array();
            while (i < 10){
                //add a day
                currentdate.setDate(currentdate.getDate() + 1);
                i++;
                //if it's a workingday add it to the array
                if (!(currentdate.getUTCDay() == 0 || currentdate.getUTCDay() == 6 )){
                    workingdays.push(currentdate);
                }
            }
            return workingdays;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you have:

```
workingdays.push([currentdate,datum,daysfromstart]);
```

you may need to put a copy of the Date object into the array, so:

```
workingdays.push([new Date(+currentdate), datum, daysfromstart]);
```

will do the job.

#### PS

Why `+currentdate`? Because if:

```
new Date(currentdate)
```

is used, *currentdate* is converted to a string (by *Date.toString*) then parsed back into a Date. The date constructor for an implementation is supposed to correctly parse the default output of its *toString* method, which they will do but if you have a date like 23 June 45 (i.e. the year 45), it will be parsed as 23 June 1945 in most browsers.

An edge case? Maybe, but for the sake of 1 character you can rest easy that dates in years 1 to 99 will be correctly copied. ;-)